# Primitive recursive functions

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science

Suppose $f_1, f_2, ... ,f_n$ is a finite list of primitive recursive functions.

Consider the set of terms $T$ that can be constructed from $f_1, .... , f_n$ and the constant $0$.

Consider the evaluation function $e$ that takes the Godel number of an element of $T$ to the natural number to which it evaluates. Must $e$ also be primitive recursive?

Of course, there is no primitive recursive function that evaluates all primitive recursive functions on all arguments, but I'm asking for something much less than that.

Comment: One way to view or define primitive recursive functions is as functions that can be computed in a programming language which has no unbounded loops (all loops must be bounded by a previously computed value), e.g., Hofstadter's “BlooP”. Clearly what you suggest is doable in such a language since the number of calls is bounded a priori.

Comment: Why isn't the natural definition of "value of a term" a perfectly good course-of-values recursion on the Gödel numbers of terms of the limited sort in your question?

Comment: Previously asked at (and in my opinion more appropriate for) MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309029/primitive-recursive-function.